# whats different about octane?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Is there a point to use octane render over cycles? What benefit does it have? I noticed there is a certain 'octane look', i have no idea why. Just curious if anyone here has used them both and can point out pros and cons.

Thanks you.

Comment: not about octane, but whatever https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UO40X_ZEj4Q

Comment: The principles of how to synthesize an image out of a 3d scene are exactly the same. However, I'd say Octane is more optimized (faster for now) and can handle instances pretty well, that's it.